# Spring Security with DelegatingFilterProxy

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have created a spring security Filter as below.

```xml
<!-- Enables Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
<!-- End Spring Security -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-        
class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/remoting-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And apart from this I can assure everything is correct. But only problem I have is,

When I access a link `http://localhost:8080/myContext/remoting/Services` the Spring Filter is not called for authentication but directly it accesses my Services.

When I add the below line in web.xml. It works correctly.

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

What doubt I have is since my filter-mapping is already defined as  /*. why should I again define one more filter-mapping.

Comment: Can you enable debugging by adding `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` and post output?

Comment: Do you have any other filters?

Comment: can you try <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: @Xaerxess: I get an Exception actually. Like this SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet remoting threw exception
java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2280)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2749)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:779)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
 at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<

Comment: @axtavt: No there is no other filter.

Comment: @SubinS: that would take only root If I am correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me successfully as I added the below snippet in the spring-security.xml

```
 <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />// pattern was modified to /**
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```